# How can I constrain a coefficient to an integer value in the least_squares function in SciPy optimization?

Tags: optimization, scipy, least-squares, scipy-optimize

I am using the 'least_squares' function from the SciPy library in Python for optimization. I want to constrain a coefficient to always be an integer value within a bound. However, the least_squares function does not seem to have a built-in option to include constraints - only bounds. Is there any way to introduce constraints in the least_sqaures function?

I have this code:

```
def objective_function(params, target):
    # ... implementation of the objective function ...

def constraint(params):
    coeff = params[0]

    if not isinstance(coeff, int):
        return False

    return True

# Input parameters
coeff_initial_guess = 2
# ... other parameters ...

# Bounds for optimization
bounds = ([1], [4])  # Bounds for coeff

# Set up the optimization problem
result = least_squares(objective_function, [coeff_initial_guess], bounds=bounds)
```

Is there a way to incorporate the constraint function into the least_squares optimization process to enforce that the coefficient remains an integer? Alternatively, are there any alternative optimization functions in SciPy that can handle such constraints?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `optimize.differential_evolution`, that function has an `integrality` keyword to allow you to specify which parameters need to be integers. You will have to reformulate your `least_squares` objective into a scalar function (e.g. `fun = np.sum(objective_function(pars)**2)`)

Answer (score 0):

For proven optimal solutions, I think you need a MIQP (Mixed-Integer Quadratic Programming) solver. Unfortunately, Scipy does not have such a solver. MIQP solvers are part of libraries like Cplex and Gurobi.

Another answer suggested using `optimize.differential_evolution`. That looks like a good idea. This is a stochastic heuristic and, in general, it does not find global optimal solutions. Your problem may be small enough, that you have a high probability of finding an optimal solution (but you will never be sure). MIQP solvers are deterministic and stop as soon as an optimal solution is found, while these heuristics just stop on some iteration or time limit. These methods are not smart enough to know whether they have solved the problem. One could stop on some probabilistic argument: the probability of finding a better solution is small enough. That is essentially what `optimize.differential_evolution` can use as a stopping criterion.

In general, I prefer deterministic solvers. I typically use stochastic heuristics only when deterministic solvers run out of steam.